# Google MapsActivity: Tileoverlay set attribution

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Mapbox TileOverlays require attribution. How can I set this in java?

Here is my code to change the tileOverlay to a custom one. The attribution I have to use is this link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright

```
overlayString = "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
provider = new CustomUrlTileProvider(256, 256, overlayString);
mSelectedTileOverlay = gMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(provider).zIndex(-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a Textview the sits on top on the mapview and has a clickable url to the copyright link